# status bar becomes gradient after closing video in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios6, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, uistatusbar

Below is happening with iOS 6.

I am playing video which can be played in potrait or landscape mode. Once video's Done button is pressed I am making screen to potrait mode programmatically.

The problem is  when I open app, I have black status bar.

When I play video as potrait only, I still see black status bar as shown below.

[image]

Now when I play video and shift rotation after after playback is done and click Done button, I make app in potrait mode. **BUT now my status bar is changed to light black (maybe BlackTransculent).**

[image]

***Also if you see, I see something black left to the time***.

**Any idea what is going wrong? This is literally making me crazy.**

---

### Edit 1

Below is the code I am using.

In viewcontroller.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

In CustomNavigation.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (![[self.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"ViewController")])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
}
```

Note:

I am not using below code anymore.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

still this problem persist...

### The problem is when I am in landscape mode and click done button.

Comment: `setOrientation:` on `UIDevice` is not public but you probably already knew that.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist : what should I use then?

Comment: @FahimParkar.. can u share your code?

Comment: @FahimParkar. Nothing seems wrong here. Can you upload your code in github? let me check it if I could help with something

Comment: @achievelimitless : I will create sample code tomorrow and upload in on github or dropbox... I will share link tomorrow once I am done...

Comment: @FahimParkar.. sure. What happened to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379449/set-alertview-yes-button-to-bold-and-no-button-to-normal).. Is it working??

Comment: @achievelimitless : Nope.. I went ahead with custom alertview...

Comment: @FahimParkar.. well then.. Feel free to accept answer .. ;)

Comment: @achievelimitless : After further investigation, I noticed that when MPMoviePlayerController is started, status bar is changing to transculent...

Comment: @FahimParkar.. great.. n what about black dot?

Comment: that is the image that I have... I have image at position (0,-416,320,460)... What I did is when I go back, I am setting statusbar to black... it is just mpmovieplayer is setting statusbar to transculent... after stopping I am trying to set it to black, but its not working... not sure WHY...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird...

After further investigation, I noticed that when video is played in landscape mode, status bar is changed to transculent.

What I tried programmatically is after video is done with playing, set status bar back to black `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];`, BUT that was not also working.

So what I did is when user hit back button, I set it to black and there it was working. Not sure what is the problem.

```
- (IBAction)takeMeBackAction:(id)sender {
    //    [self takeMeDownAction:nil];

    if (IS_DEVICE_RUNNING_IOS_6_OR_BELOW()) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    }
}
```