# set alertview Yes button to bold and No button to normal

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uialertview

I have alertview where I have Yes and No options. It looks like below.

[image]

Code used is

```
UIAlertView *confAl = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Are you sure?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
confAl.tag = 888;
[confAl show];
```

This is perfect but I want Yes to be bold and No as normal font.

So I switched the Yes and No button and have like below.

[image]

Code used is

```
UIAlertView *confAl = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Are you sure?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
confAl.tag = 888;
[confAl show];
```

***Is there any way where we can have Yes as first button and No as second button with Yes as bold effect?***

**Note :** *I want same effects in iOS 6 (same old style) & iOS 7 (new style as above in image) too.*

Comment: @downvoter : what is the problem in question? I seriously love to HATE you...

Comment: @Fahim.. Chill .. I've up voted you. don't hate that down voter ..:)

Comment: Could also try some of these : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alert+view

Comment: @JohnWoods : I don't want to go with custom alertview... I am trying to find solution with the current alertview... maybe like firstButton.title.style = bold or something like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirement is to "Highlight" Yes button.. In iOS 7 by default cancel button is the one which is highlighted. Unfortunately you can't simply change alertViewStyle here. But you do have a workaround.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125249/highlight-top-button-in-uialertview).

Comment: upvoted... can you take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364163/status-bar-becomes-gradient-after-closing-video-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: @FahimParkar.. Can't see your screenshots.. will see question after an hour.. will intimate if got any idea

Comment: "In iOS 7 by default cancel button is the one which is highlighted"? Are you sure? It's exactly the opposite in the screenshots.

Comment: @Mecki.. Ya it is.. ScreenShot might seem confusing as its up to you, what you name your cancel button. By Default, right most button is cancel button.

Answer (score 30):

You may use `preferredAction` default property of `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView`.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"My alert message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                            handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                            {

                                [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                            }];

UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                           }];

[alertController addAction:noButton];    
[alertController addAction:yesButton];
[alertController setPreferredAction:yesButton];
```

`setPreferredAction` will set your button title bold.

Comment: If we're using UIAlertController, this is the answer

Comment: Since UIAlertView is being [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertview), this is the best answer going forward

Comment: I'm also using `setPreferredAction` in my code. But this *crashes* in iOS8 as it was not available in iOS8.
Do you have any solution which will work consistently on iOS 8 and above?

Comment: I found a solution for my above mentioned question.
We should add device specific check for API `setPreferredAction` as it should be called only if the device is iOS 9 and above.

Additionally, I observed that below iOS 9, UIAlertController internally highlights the last added action (button). (It is not mentioned in [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/1620094-addaction) that UIAlertController will be highlighting the last added action)